# Change styling of dragImage while dragging

Tags: javascript, html

I call the `setDragImage` on `dragstart`, I then want to update the image while I am dragging over certain elements. When I call `setDragImage` again, from within the `dragover` callback it doesn't change anything.
Currently I am using a element as an image:

```
row.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(document.getElementsByClassName('drag-image')
[0],40,40);
});
```

I tried calling the setDragImage again in dragover:

```
row.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
  if (dragOverSomeCondition) {
    var dataTransfer = e.dataTransfer || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    dataTransfer.setDragImage(document.getElementsByClassName('drag-image-with-plus')
[0],40,40);
  }
});
```

The drag image does not seem to change when called inside the drag over callback.

Comment: Please include more of your code.

Comment: @BPS I have edited my answer, I hope that clarifies it

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same problem, and cant seem to find a solution for it. Did you manage to solve it?